# Finding object count where a field is unique in Django

Tags: django

I have a model that is something like this:

```
class Input(models.Model):
        details = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Case(Input):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    views = models.IntegerField()

    class Argument(Input):
        case = models.ForeignKey(Case)
        side = models.BooleanField()
```

A user can submit many arguments, per case.  I want to be able to say how many users have submitted `side=true` arguments.

I mean if 1 user had 10 arguments and another user had 2 arguments (both `side=true`)
I'd want the count to be 2, not 12.

#### Update:

I am using these methods on the Case object:

```
 def users_agree(self):
        return self.argument_set.filter(side=True).values('user').distinct()
    def users_disagree(self):
        return self.argument_set.filter(side=False).values('user').distinct()
```

My template code calls `count()` on them.

Comment: I hope you are not actually using "case" Python keyword in your code.

Comment: I didn't know python has a keyword case.  Can you refer me to docs on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Argument.objects.filter(side=True).values('case__user').distinct().count()
```

I think it does what you want. It issues one SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "example_input"."user_id") FROM "example_argument" INNER JOIN "example_case" ON ("example_argument"."case_id" = "example_case"."input_ptr_id") INNER JOIN "example_input" ON ("example_case"."input_ptr_id" = "example_input"."id") WHERE "example_argument"."side" = True
```

Edit:

For `this_case`, get all users whose argument.side is True:

```
Argument.objects.filter(case__id=this_case.id, side=True).values('user').distinct()
```

Comment: Come to think of it, this should probably be done of the Case object.  Like 'for this case show me how many users are on what side'

Comment: I've added another query to address your new requirement. Can you try?

Comment: NameError: name 'this_case' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, you said "for this case show ...". Replace this_case with the Case object for which you want users whose argument.side is True.

Comment: I'm gong to call this on a instance of a Case object, so I don't think I'll need to specify a case

Comment: If this is going to be in a Case method, replace this_case.id with self.id. By the way, I made a correction to the query.

Comment: def get_users_agree(self):
        return self.argument_set.filter(side=True).values('user').distinct()


do you see an issue with this?